# Exibindo Bitmap em aplicação C#

Tags: c#, winforms, bitmap, drawing

Tenho o seguinte codigo na minha aplicação :

```
Bitmap original = new Bitmap("C:/Projeto/Imagens/antialiasing.jpg");
Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(original);
g.DrawImage(original, 100, 100, 390, 390);
```

Porém não está sendo exibido na tela a imagem `original`. O que devo fazer para exibir.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Raphael, esta é uma aplicação winform? voce está mostrando esta imagem em um PictureBox?

Se for o caso, você pode colocar a imagem diretamente o pictureBox.

```
Bitmap original = new Bitmap("C:/Projeto/Imagens/antialiasing.jpg");
pictureBox1.Image = original;
```

Bom, não sei se era esta a sua duvida.

Comment: Isso mesmo que era minha duvida.